# Footnote indent equal to text parindent

Tags: indentation, footnotes

Is there a way to save the document `\parindent` and use it to indent footnotes? I am using `koma-script`, therefore I would like to use the `\deffootnote[mark width]{indent}{parindent}{definition}` command.

A MWE is

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
%\deffootnote[1em]{0em}{1em}{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}}

\parindent = 20pt

\deffootnote[\dim\the\parindent]{0em}{\the\parindent}{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}}

\begin{document}

Here it will be placed a footnote\footnote{This is a footnote!}.

\end{document}
```

But it doesn't work as expected!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Save (at begin document) the value of the normal parindent and use it for the footnotes.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\deffootnote[\normalparindent]
            {0em}
            {\normalparindent}
            {\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}}
\newlength{\normalparindent}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\normalparindent}{\parindent}}

\begin{document}

Here it will be placed a footnote\footnote{This is a footnote!}.

\end{document}
```